# CSS on home page only

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using Mdboostrap on my "top-navbar" and "sidenavbar" in my web pages.
The Mdboostrap uses its own CSS file i.e. mdb.min.css 
Using the above CSS file creates a conflict with the layout of other web pages.

It is therefore required to limit the CSS of mdbootrap upto the home file only. 
To do so, I have tried assigning a unique classname/ID to body of home page and then specified a CSS for it but to no avail.

Please suggest your valuable guidelines so that the issue as stated may be resolved.

Thanks for the helping in advance!
- Shatrughan

Comment: I don't get it, why not just link `mdb.min.css` to the home page only? Unless you are saying that you require `mdb.min.css` for every page you have, but the classes used are somehow the same as yours

Comment: The said mdb.min.css is included in home page(header.php) only which is further included in other php files to have the header in all web pages.

Comment: ***To do so, I have tried assiging a unique classname/ID to body of home page and then specifying css for it but to no avail.*** Show us where you have done this.

Comment: Here is the link to my web page containing "mdbootstrap snippet" https://e-reporting.in/Depot/RTC/index.php and below is the link to "mdbootstrap snippet" where topnav and sidenav are defined. https://e-reporting.in/Depot/RTC/snippet/index.php